I get an error like that "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."
I'm trying to write my first API to connect to SQL Server. I have been following all the steps from a tutorial, but I only obtain this error. I have heard this error is because the wrong connection string is wrong.
However, I have tested all the way to correct the connection string but nothing changes.
This my appsettings.json file:
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Cafe;User Id=s2;Password=s2;"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Code in my controller:
using APISQL.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using APIPuenteSQL.Context;
// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace APISQL.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class productosController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ProductosContext _context;

        public productosController(ProductosContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/<productosController>
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Productos>> GetAll()
        {
            // Here stops the running when I try to list through Swagger
            return _context.Producto.ToList(); 
        }
    }
}

Error message

System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary2 synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.<>c.<get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled>b__7_0(String cs)   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func2 valueFactory)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.GenerateCacheKey(Expression query, Boolean async)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable1.GetEnumerator()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()   at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
at APIPuenteSQL.Controllers.productosController.GetAll() in E:\Restaurantes\AppRestaurante\APIPuenteSQL\Context\productosController.cs:line 25
at lambda_method2(Closure, Object, Object[])
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: text/plain
Host: localhost:7082
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9
Referer: https://localhost:7082/swagger/index.html
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
priority: u=1, i

I'm using Entity Framework Core v8.0.7.
I am following the instructions in this material on the web.
https://www.royrojas.com/como-crear-una-api-rest-con-asp-net-core-6-0/
I tried several forms of connection string and got nowhere. Those attempts work fine in other areas, except with my API.

We would need to see how you are setting up this dbcontext for dependency injection, within your application's startup code.  Showing us the HTTP headers is useless.

This error indicates an invalid connection string keyword. Consult the official Microsoft.Data.SqlClient documentation for keywords rather than some random web page. I believe Database= should be Initial Catalog= .

Cannot reproduce https://dotnetfiddle.net/gOWM8w that is a valid string
